# How to iterate through a module's functions

Tags: python, functional-programming, getattr

I have this function call after importing foo.py. Foo has several methods that I need to call e.g. foo.paint, foo.draw:

```
import foo

code

if foo:
    getattr(foo, 'paint')()
```

I need to use a while loop to call and iterate through all the functions foo.paint, foo.draw etc. How do i go about it?

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate. In that question the OP only wanted information, in this one he actually wants to call the functions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `foo.__dict__` somehow like this:

```
for name, val in foo.__dict__.iteritems(): # iterate through every module's attributes
    if callable(val):                      # check if callable (normally functions)
        val()                              # call it
```

But watch out, this will execute every function (callable) in the module. If some specific function receives any arguments it will fail.

A more elegant (functional) way to get functions would be:

```
[f for _, f in foo.__dict__.iteritems() if callable(f)]
```

For example, this will list all functions in the `math` method:

```
import math
[name for name, val in math.__dict__.iteritems() if callable(val)]
['pow',
 'fsum',
 'cosh',
 'ldexp',
 ...]
```

Comment: being new to python am a bit confused on how to implement this: [f for _, f in foo.__dict__.iteritems() if callable(f)]. I get AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @wakamdr Seems you're using Python 3, try with `__dict__.items()`