# xmlrpcserver implementation in python capable of registering an entire module?

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I have a system where the code sits on a driver accessing a remote system.  I'm using the SimpleXmlRpcServer implementation of xmlrpcserver and it works quite well.  Functions and instances can be registered, but i dont think entire modules can be registered. In particular, id like to register the os module.  Is this a possibility with simplexmlrpcserver or are there any other implementations that allow for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate over the methods in the module and register each of them with `register_instance`.

For example, using [this `SimpleXMLRPCServer` example as a starting point](http://pymotw.com/2/SimpleXMLRPCServer/) and [this Stackoverflow answer for iterating over functions in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21885920/4486839):

**Server**

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import os

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 9000))

def list_contents(dir_name):
    return os.listdir(dir_name)
for name, val in os.__dict__.items():
    if callable(val):
        print "Registering " +  name
        server.register_function(val, name)

try:
    print 'Use Control-C to exit'
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Exiting'
```

**Client**

```
import xmlrpclib

proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:9000')
print 'os.listdir():', proxy.listdir('.')
```